# Averaging linear regression model using AIC's relative likelihood

Tags: regression, aic, linear

I've learned [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Akaike_information_criterion#/How_to_apply_AIC_in_practice) that when two models have a big relative likelihood, one could compute a weighted average of those models in order to estimate the "unconditional" variable effect. However, some questions remain unclear:

1. What is considered a "big enough" relative likelihood? Can I average over several models? If so, why should I omit any model at all, as an unlikely model would get a near zero weight anyways?
2. What should I do with insignificant effects? should I skip them when averaging? What is considered a "small enough" p-value?

Comment: Q1. If doing prediction and there are several models that are (relatively to each other) reasonable fits, then why not weight their predictions. But if some candidate models have very low relative likelihood, why keep them around? They are poor fit to the data as their Akaike weights would indicate. Q2. The information criteria, AIC included, don't give p-values, so it's unclear what you mean.